# If a function $f:X \to Y$ is continuous on any compact subset $K \subseteq X$, is $f$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I hope I phrased that right. If $X$ is not able to be covered by a family of compact spaces, how could we prove this? Am I just missing something simple?

(Let $f:X \to Y$ (EDIT: $X$ and $Y$ metric spaces) have the property such that $\forall K\subseteq X$ such that $K$ is compact, $f|_{K}:X \to Y$ is continuous. This is supposed to lead to $f$ being continuous but I am really lost...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What conditions are imposed on $X$? If it can be an arbitrary topological space, I'm almost sure the conclusion need not hold.

Comment: Just that $X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces

Comment: Ah _metric_ spaces. Then it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For metric spaces, continuity is equivalent to sequential continuity, that is, for each convergent sequence $x_n \to x$, one has $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

Now, if $x_n\to x$, then the set $\{x\} \cup \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is compact.

Comment: What is really urking me is if we have an $x \in X$ such that it does not belong to any compact set... I will go back to my books and see what else I can find

Comment: Every $x\in X$ belongs to some compact set. Perhaps your concern is with such $x$ that no nontrivial sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$ exists? But then $x$ is an isolated point of $X$, and every function is continuous in every isolated point (you don't even need a metric for that).

Comment: That helped a ton! So for simplicity, we can say $f$ is cont. on any isolated points.

So if we take an arbitrary sequence such that $x_{n} \to x$, where $x$ is not isolated, there must exist an $N$ such that $\forall n \geq N$, $x_{n} \in K$, some compact space. Because $f$ is continuous on $K$, we have $f(x_{n}) \to f(x)$. So $f$ is cont. at $x$. $x$ being arbitrary, $f$ is cont. on $X$.

I think I might have done something wrong here, but I have a much better idea of how to get there. Thank you!

Comment: You can take the underlying set of the sequence together with the limit for $K$. That's the point, such sets are compact, so if $f\lvert_K$ is continuous for every compact $K$, then $f$ is sequentially continuous. For nice spaces like metric spaces, that means $f$ is continuous.

Comment: OH! Gotcha! (Eureka moment) Now I see what you meant by your original comment. Thank you very, very much.